# sqlsrv_query executing not returning result, but result exists when code executed in sql manager

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm trying to execute the code below, but for some reason, it is not returning any result, it is not reporting any errors, and I can't figure out why. When I paste the query directly to SQL Manager, it is executed, and I get the desired result.

I assume it's something with sqlsrv_query that is interpreting differently, but I can't figure out why.

It's a first time; I'm trying to do it with PHP so I'm struggling and I would appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction.

```
 $sql = "DECLARE @YearsToPass INT
    SET @YearsToPass = 10;
    WITH cte AS
    (
    SELECT DATEPART(YY, GETDATE())- @YearsToPass + 1 as Years
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Years + 1 as Years
    FROM cte
    WHERE Years + 1 <= YEAR(GETDATE())
    )

    SELECT cte.Years, DATEFROMPARTS(cte.Years, 12, 31),  SUM(Inv.[Nabavna vrijednost])
    FROM cte
    left join  [Drezga01].[dbo].[BI_Inventory01] Inv on Inv.[Datum knjiženja] <= DATEFROMPARTS(cte.Years, 12, 31)
    group by cte.Years, DATEFROMPARTS(cte.Years, 12, 31)
    ORDER BY cte.Years DESC";
 $query = sqlsrv_query($conn_bi,$sql);
 //error handling
 if( $query === false ) {
    if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
     foreach( $errors as $error ) {
     echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
     echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
     echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
     }
   }
  }
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
$zaliha_array[] = array('godina' => $row['godina'],
                        'zaliha' => abs($row['nabava']));
}

 debugVar($zaliha_array);
```

Array is empty, but no errors reported. Result exists and is returned when query executed in SQL Management Studio. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you make a small test and execute your script with this error checking: `$query = sqlsrv_query($conn_bi, $sql); if ($query === false ) {print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true); exit;}`. Thanks.

Comment: No, no errors. But no result also?  I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generate statement, that has no column aliases for `DATEFROMPARTS(cte.Years, 12, 31)` and `SUM(Inv.[Nabavna vrijednost])` and using [sqlsrv_fetch_array()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-fetch-array?view=sql-server-2017) with `SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC` is one possible reason for your unexpected results.
Try to fetch data with `SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC` option to retrieve each row of a result set as a numerically indexed array:

```
<?php
$sql = "
    DECLARE @YearsToPass INT
    SET @YearsToPass = 10;

    WITH cte AS
    (
        SELECT DATEPART(YY, GETDATE())- @YearsToPass + 1 as Years
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Years + 1 as Years
        FROM cte
        WHERE Years + 1 <= YEAR(GETDATE())
    )

    SELECT cte.Years, DATEFROMPARTS(cte.Years, 12, 31),  SUM(Inv.[Nabavna vrijednost])
    FROM cte
    left join  [Drezga01].[dbo].[BI_Inventory01] Inv on Inv.[Datum knjiženja] <= DATEFROMPARTS(cte.Years, 12, 31)
    group by cte.Years, DATEFROMPARTS(cte.Years, 12, 31)
    ORDER BY cte.Years DESC
";

$query = sqlsrv_query($conn_bi, $sql);
if ($query === false ) {
    print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)){
    $zaliha_array[] = array(
        'godina' => $row[0],
        'zaliha' => abs($row[2])
    );
}
debugVar($zaliha_array);
?>
```

Comment: Spot on! I just added aliases for columns and it worked like a charm. Can't believe it was so simple and I spent hours trying to figure out what is going on. Thank you very much @Zhorov!

Comment: @BudimirSkrtic I'm glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have some requirements for this communication to work properly:

1. You need to check the operating system requirements, sql server version and php version. Then you download the driver for your version of php. This link can help you with this step [System requirements for the microsoft drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017)
2. Download and install the ODBC driver. [You can download ODBC Driver here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56567)
3. Make reference of the drivers that you downloaded in php.ini where the extensions are
   [as this picture shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDFF5.png)

   Obs: Do not forget to take the ';' before the word extension

   Obs: Do not forget that the driver files need to be in the php / ext directory which is where the php drivers are
4. Finally use the phpinfo() function and verify that the pdo_sqlsrv extension has been loaded. [he should stay like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6ixC.png)

I hope this helps to solve the problem o/

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is misleading, but my connection with MS SQL is OK. I'm able to perform SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE queries. Only the above query is a problem for me, that one is not returning anything.